# Is it possible to play just a part of an mp3 file with AVAudioPlayer? If yes, how?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, avaudioplayer, avfoundation

Hi I have a locally stored 5:00 minutes mp3 files in my iPhone app.

I would like to know if it is possible to play just an interval from that file using AVAudioPlayer after it is readyToPlay, lets say from 0:25 to 1:34.

If it is possible how can I achieve that?

I know I can move the playhead cursor using setCurrentTime: but how do I let the AVAudioPlayer know how many seconds it should play from that currentTime.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to set a timer which will stop that playing after particular time interval.

Comment: Can you play just a chunk of an AVAudioPlayer mp3? Eg "from 10 to 15 seconds" - and is this comparative in speed to having a separate file with just that 5 second chunk?

Comment: having a separate file of 5 seconds will always be good... coz new how you cannot stop the player by providing particular timeframe. You have to start one NSTimer in the background to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

@Horatiu you can use `NSTimer` to schedule it for a particular time interval after you have use `setCurrentTime:` method, and in the selector method of the `NSTimer` you can make the audioPlayer stop.

Answer (score 0):

Fire a timer when you start playing the file. When the required time is reached `pause` or `stop` the player